# How to Enable "joomla extension and apply to modules"

Tags: joomla2.5

I installed this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677

I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

In Plug-in manager, I enabled It.

Than In Module manager, I created "Moving text" module and in "Custom output" , I entered the code :

{text =scrollig text }

But it's not working here you can visit this link and see in footer http://naadiastrology.info/

Why it's not working or how to use this extension.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: Have you enabled `Options -> Prepare Content` in the module?

Comment: No, i will check it now.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it in "moving text" module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this tag in **html mode** of your joomla editor like:

[image]

It works for me.

Then,if yet the text is not moving, you have to check the properties of your text editor plugin  so as to accept this kind of tags 
{...}. It seems that editor filters that tag and plugin cannot render the result!

Comment: Tell me the result of html after pressing update to the editor

Comment: I got this one: Plug-in Manager: Editor - CodeMirror.

Comment: Mine is <p>{text= your scrolling text}</p>.Yours?

Comment: So the editor is not accepting the {} try to change some options of its plugin or disable it just to add the module and then enable it

Comment: Change the editor add the module .It works ok with me

Comment: hi, this also enabled : Plug-in Manager: Editor - TinyMCE .

Comment: Last one .Go to the plugin of the editor and check Prohibited Elements if there is something or play with the options.

Comment: Hi, you are genius, finally it's working.

please visit this link : http://naadiastrology.info/.

Thanka a lot for your help.